# ASP Format to percentage specific row of gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview, string-formatting, percentage

I have a fixed size table databound to a gridview from a stored procedure:

[image]

Note: the table is 17 columns long.

Currently I'm using a `For..Next` statement to alter the background colour of the percentage row. Can I adapt this to use `DataFormatString="{0:0.0%}"` instead of the backcolor attribute or should I be doing this another way?

Here's my code which currently turns the background of the row purple:

```
    For colCount As Integer = 1 To 17
        For rowCount As Integer = 1 To 1
            gvAttainmentGrid.Rows(rowCount).Cells(colCount).Attributes = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(177, 160, 199)
        Next
    Next
```

**EDIT**

I've made some progress. I have updated my `For..Next` and although this displays OK on page load, when I select a different value in the control or add the element to my pre-render procedure it errors out with the message:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

My code now looks like the following:

```
    For colCount As Integer = 1 To 17
        For rowCount As Integer = 1 To 1
            gvAttainmentGrid.Rows(rowCount).Cells(colCount).Text = FormatPercent(Convert.ToDecimal(gvAttainmentGrid.Rows(rowCount).Cells(colCount).Text), 1)
        Next
    Next
```